# Can an alternative solution be an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have just seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642395/java-chess-unsure-how-to-clone-properly) and know an alternative solution. The question is asking about how to clone stuff properly because he/she is doing a chess program. I have another way to write a chess program so should I post it in the answers or the comments?

Comment: Post an answer.

Comment: While it will of course be useful to the OP it will not at all help future readers who come to the question from Google with a similar problem. This has happened to me where I've found a question just like I was asking but the answer did not help me because an alternate solution was provided instead of an answer to the original question

Comment: @Aequitas Some questions get tens of thousands of views from Google, often long after they were originally posted. Are you really suggesting that an alternative solution to a problem would be helpful to *none* of those people?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I don't know, if it's *none* but it will definitely decrease the chance that's it's useful to someone. I'm not saying that an alternate answer should or should not be posted. I'm just pointing out that people will be viewing the question expecting a certain Q&A but getting something unrelated to the question.

Comment: Looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/152923)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you have enough content to create an answer, then you absolutely should post an answer.

The answer doesn't always have to answer the OP's specific problem, it can detail a different way to achieve what they want, thereby avoiding the issue they were facing.

Keep in mind that there are no guarantees that the OP will accept your answer, and simply showing a different way won't always get you positive attention from viewers, so you should illustrate why your approach is better.

Comment: I agree. It is important to remember that at the end of the day, SO serves as a repository of information. While the original answer may show how to clone one way, your answer/alternative may better suit someone else who stumbles upon that question.

Answer (score 2):

If your alternative might be helpful for the OP, I'd strongly encourage you to put it into an answer. However, I prefer answers that at least include a basic answer to the question that was actually asked (which should be their primary purpose, no?).

So I think you should at least address the actual question, even if that repeats content which can be found in another answer (of course you can just give a short summary and refer to one of the other answers for a detailed explanation).
Then you can add value to it, by making additional suggestions on how to further improve the OP's program or alternative approaches to the problem.

Comment: "even if that repeats content which can be found in another answer", repeating content is rarely if ever a good idea.

Comment: @apaul: I hope you can see the irony in that comment. But seriously: Almost all answers to the same question share similar content, but differ in the way they convey/explein that content. Also, I think it is much better, if there is one answer that contains all information, rather thanhaving to read all of them. So if am answer e.g. answers only part of a question,  I doubt anyone would complain, if someone else posted a complete one, that includes the bits from the first one rather than just adding the missing pieces.

Comment: I don't like the statement of "I don't like answers that don't answer the actual".. That is like saying OP asks *"How do I get to the moon with a spoon and a firecracker?"* The right answer for this question might be ... *"You just have to position the firecracker so that it achieves the proper boost from the Earth's rotation at a 45 degree angle on a Sunday afternoon just after the 32 second of the hour. The spoon isn't needed."* But the best approach would really be *"Go on a space ship you fool."*

Comment: What I'm saying is sometimes an alternative answer is much more appropriate than a direct answer to a flawed question.

Comment: @CayceK: I agree that there are cases, where the correct answer is just: *"It's not possible / sensible at all because..."* (which doesn't contradict my statement btw.). And I also agree that there are cases, where an alternative approach is more helpful for the questionair. But, while the first (almost) always implies the second, the reverse is not automatically true and the question we are discussing here is a good example for this.

Comment: I do see this. I only frown because of the statement I quoted. I want to remove my downvote, but I'm limited by time. If you edit this sometime from now I will remove it, but I want you to know I believe you're more open to this than initially read.

Comment: @CayceK: I see your point and reformulated that sentence.